# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or propert

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Me pueden decir sobre como solucionar este error,

```
  BizCall(
         new Action(() =>
             {
                 result = crudFunction.GetKitchenParameter("ReleaseGroupedComms", bizKitchenConfiguration.ScreenId);
             }
         )
        );
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
        {
            var section = result.Split('|');
         //  BizKitchenNEWConfiguration.IsReleaseGroupedComms = section[1];
        }
        else
        {
         //  BizKitchenNEWConfiguration.IsReleaseGroupedComms = "NO";
        }
```

En la parte comentada es donde me salta el error y aca esta el get

```
namespace Parrot.Kitchen.Business.Entities.Model
{
     public class BizKitchenNEWConfiguration
    {
        public int GroupMinutes { get; set; }
        public int GroupCommands { get; set; }
        public string IsReleaseGroupedComms { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Dónde instancias la clase **BizKitchenNEWConfiguration**?

Comment: Como bien te dice @PauloUrbanoRivera, `BizKitchenNEWConfiguration` es una clase **no estatica**. Si quieres acceder a sus propiedades, primero tienes que instanciarla.

Comment: Agradezco sus comentarios, estoy viendo eso, para solucionarlo, gracias

Comment: donde instancias crudFunction y bizKitchenConfiguration ? se supone que deberias tener la instancia previamente